# Which software can be used to do file (PHP source code) comparison

Tags: php, file, comparison

I have the latest version of code in my website(Quite a few PHP files are modified). but the code that i have in my local host is bit older.

Are there any file-comparison applications to find the latest modified code?

Comment: I would look at some form of version control system.

Comment: Okay, comment flaggers, I think in this case "FTW" stands for "for the win".  You can stop flagging now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You want `diff` to compare files, but more to the point, you should be using a version control system so you don't have these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

[ExamDiff](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiff.asp)... One .exe file that would solve your problem.